# Button ControlTemplate - TextBlock narrows as more text added

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate, textblock

I am trying to make a Button ControlTemplate in which the the text will scale itself within the control. I have had some amount of success, but one issue is still plaguing me: The more text I add to the button, the narrower the TextBlock gets -- so the text doesn't span the width of the button. To illustrate:

[image]

And here is my template code:

```
    <Style
        x:Key="OptionButton"
        TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="75" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,0,5,0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid Height="70">
                    <Rectangle
                        Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                        Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                        Stretch="Fill"
                        Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        StrokeThickness="1">
                        <Rectangle.Clip>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Converter={StaticResource ButtonBackRectConverter}}" />
                        </Rectangle.Clip>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <Ellipse
                        Width="70"
                        Height="70"
                        Stretch="Fill"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        StrokeThickness="1">
                        <Ellipse.Clip>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,35,70" />
                        </Ellipse.Clip>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <Ellipse
                        Width="70"
                        Height="70"
                        Stretch="Fill"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        StrokeThickness="1">
                        <Ellipse.Clip>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="35,0,35,70" />
                        </Ellipse.Clip>
                    </Ellipse>

                    <Viewbox
                        StretchDirection="DownOnly"
                        Stretch="Uniform">

                        <ContentPresenter
                            Name="ToastButtonContentPresenter"
                            TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding TextBlock.Foreground}"
                            Style="{StaticResource LargeText}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" >

                            <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" />
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
                                    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                                </Style>
                            </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Would greatly appreciate any guidance to help me solve this problem.

Comment: You are using a `Viewbox`, see what happens once you remove it.

Comment: If your goal is to have it all on one line, then you're going to have to remove the TextWrapping=Wrap property/instruction. That or remove the width binding, which is redundant inside a viewbox, because the second the viewbox tries to resize it, the width is arbitrary and will cause a steady growth of that left-and-right margin you showed.

Comment: @anjumskhan, on removing the Viewbox, the text no longer resizes down to fit the button. Long button texts get truncated.

Comment: @Logan, perhaps I should have specified that the goal is to have wrappable button text that shrinks to fit as needed.

Comment: @BobbyTait: I see, for that, you will need to define some actual parameters to tell the text when to 'put its foot down' for lack of a better term and say I'm not going to allow any more text in this line. With a max width. But then that max width will also need to grow intelligently to make sure there's no left-and-right margin as is occurring with your current code.

Comment: @Logan, I've tinkered with a ValueConverter and tried setting MaxWidth properties to no avail. In all attempts, the text remained tiny, as if wrapping was turned off. Once, the text stretched across the width of the button and wrapped. Other times, it seemed like the vertical alignment had changed.

Answer (score 0):

One idea can be to use a converter in width and height property of the button and pass the text length as parameter.

Based on the length you can write your logic and return a new length.

> Width = "{Binding ButtonText, Converter={StaticResource
>   TextToLengthConverter}, ConverterParameter=ButtonText}"

Above is only pseudo code. Try and let me know.

Comment: I'd like to keep the button size static, and adjust the TextBlock size to better fit.

In trying to work with your idea, I set the ValueConverter in the TextBlock's ContentPresenter's Style properties, but still have not gotten desirable results.